# Racket basic question

Tags: racket

I'm beginning Racket, and (being a rookie) I'm having some trouble finding out what's exactly wrong with my code. At first, I tried implementing the thing as a single function, and it worked fine:

```
; Finds surface area of pipe
; outside surface area (2pir+thickness)*length
; inside SA 2pirad*length
; 2 (area of outer circle - area of inner circle)
; add all together
(define (area-pipe inner_radius height thickness)
  (+ (* 2 pi inner_radius height)
     (* 2 pi height (+ inner_radius thickness))
     (- (* 2 pi (sqr (+ inner_radius thickness)))
             (* 2 pi (sqr inner_radius)))))
```

And (since I'm following the tutorials provided [here](http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1730/2010/Assignments/support/tutorial1.pdf)), I set out to implement this as a combination of functions, to which I ended up with the following:

```
; functional implementation
(define (area-circle radius)
  (* 2 pi (sqr radius)))
(define (area-cylinder radius height)
  (* 2 pi (sqr radius) height))
;actual function--why doesn't this quite work as planned?
(define (area-pipe1 inner_radius height thickness)
  (+ (area-cylinder inner_radius height)
     (area-cylinder (+ inner_radius thickness) height)
     (- (area-circle (+ inner_radius thickness))
        (area-circle inner_radius))))
```

So, I'm *guessing* that there's a problem with my definitions. However, I'd appreciate some hints and nudges towards why I'm not receiving the right answers.
As tests, the site provides the following code:

```
(test (area-pipe1 0.5 0 0.5) 4.71)
(test (area-pipe1 0 2 1) 18.85)
(test (area-pipe1 1 2 1) 56.54)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `area-cylinder` is wrong. It should take the *circumference* and multiply by the height. Thus:

```
(define (area-cylinder radius height)
  (* 2 pi radius height))
```

Your `area-circle` is also wrong. It should be thus:

```
(define (area-circle radius)
  (* pi radius radius))
```

So the `area-pipe` function should be:

```
(define (area-pipe2 inner-radius height thickness)
  (+ (area-cylinder inner-radius height)
     (area-cylinder (+ inner-radius thickness) height)
     (* 2 (- (area-circle (+ inner-radius thickness))
             (area-circle inner-radius)))))
```